# Bootstrap image thumbnail container no gap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i   created image galery with caption at top using thumbnail class from bootstrap like this :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
          <p style="font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
          <a href="google.com" target="_blank" style=""> View more </a>
        </div>
        <a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" target="_blank" style="">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
          <p style="font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
          <a href="google.com" target="_blank" style=""> View more </a>
        </div>
        <a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" target="_blank" style="">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
          <p style="font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
          <a href="google.com" target="_blank" style=""> View more </a>
        </div>
        <a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" target="_blank" style="">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the problem is there is a little right, left, and bottom gap like this: 
[image: gap example]

i want the thumbnail cotainer border to fit with the image size, is there a way to do this?

Comment: you should use the `padding` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update custom style**

**[Fiddle Demo](http://hhttps://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30584/)**

```
.thumbnail
{
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

**Snippet Example**

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.thumbnail
{
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
            <p style="font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
            <a  href="google.com" target="_blank" style=""> View more </a>
        </div>
        <a href="/w3images/lights.jpg" target="_blank" style="">
          <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
            <p style="font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
            <a  href="google.com" target="_blank" style=""> View more </a>
        </div>
        <a href="/w3images/lights.jpg" target="_blank" style="">
          <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
            <p style="font-weight:bold;">Lorem ipsum donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
            <a  href="google.com" target="_blank" style=""> View more </a>
        </div>
        <a href="/w3images/lights.jpg" target="_blank" style="">
          <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.col-md-6 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Or

```
.col-md-6 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the padding tag to the row. then it has nog whitespace with the container

```
.row {
    padding: 0;
}

<div class="row">
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is a gap is because the thumbnail class has padding.
To fix this you have to remove it...

```
.thumbnail{
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```